# Evaluate: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sec^2 (\frac{1}{n^2})+\frac{2}{n^2}\sec^2 (\frac{4}{n^2})+.............+\frac{n}{n^2}\sec^2 (1)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Here is my problem in which i encountered difficulty in evaluating it.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sec^2 (\frac{1}{n^2})+\frac{2}{n^2}\sec^2 (\frac{4}{n^2})+.............+\frac{n}{n^2}\sec^2 (1)$$

My intuition shows that there will be some differentiation technique to solve it since it has the term $\sec^2 (x)$. But i couldn't figure out.Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Express this as an integral. as $\int_{l_1}^{l_2}x \sec^2 x^2 dx$ I will let you find the limits. ^^ Answer i think is $\frac{1}{2} \tan 1$ hoping no calculation error,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum can be converted into $$\int_{0}^{1}x sec^2{x^2}  dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}dt(\sec^{2}(t))=\frac{1}{2} \tan 1
$$

Comment: any different to the comment above?

Comment: yupp..got it...thanks

Comment: @Chinny84you  If by "different" you mean anything other than limit of sum, then no